# Upgrade eclipse 3.5(Galileo) JUnit

Tags: eclipse, junit

I would like to upgrade the JUnit version of my Eclipse Galileo (on windows) to JUnit 4.8.1 instead of the included JUnit 4.5.  There does not appear to be a plugin update to use the new version or a way to change the location of the JUnit 4 jars. How can I update to the new version and/or use a JUnit jar not under the eclipse install directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### For plain java projects

You could add the junit.jar you want to use as a file in your project, add it to the build path, and remove the eclipse defined junit library from the build path (assuming it was there).

### For plugin projects

You can do as above or, create a new plugin from the junit 4.8 jar and add it to your test plugin's dependencies.

Comment: This is a plain java project.  Will adding the updated JUnit jar as a Refrenced Library cause Eclipse to run JUnit tests with the runners and features from the updated JUnit?  I don't think it will.

Comment: No, I don't think it will affect the runner that the IDE uses, but I would expect that your test code would see the junit code from the reference library at run time.  I guess it depends on what new features of JUnit you want to take advantage of.

Comment: Well, maybe its not that simple. Im having a similar problem trying to override the Eclipse Ant plugin by adding a newer ant to the top of my build path and it didn't help.   So, theres probably more to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note: <del>Eclipse Galileo 3.5.2 (just released today)</del>, and Eclipse Helios 3.6M5 (to be released) have JUnit4.8 in them.
See this [Planning Meeting Notes from last January, 27th](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse-dev/msg08782.html).

Darn... As The [OP Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227344/andrew) comments, the latest Eclipse 3.5.2 still got a JUnit4.5.
As [stevendick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131652/stevendick) adds: it shouldn't make it in the 3.5 release cycle, but should probably make it in the last 3.6Mx releases.

Comment: I have updated previously today, and am running 3.5.2r352 of org.eclipse.jdt my junit.jar in plugins is still 4.5.0

Comment: I'd be surprised that a bug-fix release of Eclipse (3.5.2) contained such a major upgrade to junit - I'm doing an upgrade to check this now.  You could call those planning meeting notes ambiguous on the item about JUnit 4.8.1 - I suspect it applies only to the 3.6 milestone.

Comment: @stevendick: agreed. I just updated the answer to reflect just that.